# Reading data within parenthesis

Tags: java, string

I have a `string` something like

```
String test = "Happy{{Sad}Blue{{Red}Green}}Purple";
```

How could I extract the text between the parenthesis, like the following

1. `{Sad}Blue{{Red}Green}`
2. `Sad`
3. `{Red}Green`
4. `Red`

Comment: Not clear, Out of the 4 options provided , which one you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shouldn't, but check this out:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(test.replace("{", "\\{(").replace("}", ")\\}")).matcher(test);
m.find();
for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println(m.group(i));
}
```

[**Ideone Demo**](https://ideone.com/fck6lC)

Comment: That's evil. Brilliant. And will break if the string contains meta-characters like `(`.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to use the recursive call or the stack data struct to solve the problem. And you can understand what's behind. Here is an example:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "Happy{{Sad}Blue{{Red}Green}}Purple";
        findStr(test);

    }
    public static void findStr(String str){
        if(str==null || str.equals("")){
            return ;
        }
        int begin =0;
        int end = 0;
        String theStr = "";
        for(int i =0;i<str.length();i++){
            if(str.charAt(i) == '{'){
                begin ++ ;
                if(begin > 1){
                    theStr += str.charAt(i);
                }
            } else if (str.charAt(i) == '}'){
                end ++ ;
                if(begin == end ){
                    System.out.println(theStr);
                    findStr(theStr);
                    begin = 0;
                    end = 0;
                    theStr = "";
                }else{
                    theStr += str.charAt(i);
                }
            }else if(begin > 0 ){
                theStr += str.charAt(i);
            }
        }

    }
```